# How to have two separate query-sets under the same class based view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

I am trying to have a friends list of all the people who are connected to you with href that sends you to their profile but get:

```
`Reverse for 'view_profile_with_pk' not found. 'view_profile_with_pk' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

in the  HTML traceback details i get :

```
return render (request, self.template_name, args)
```

Views.py

```
class ViewProfile(generic.ListView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'
        def view_profile(request, pk=None):
            if pk:
                user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
            else:
                user = request.user
            kwargs = {'user': request.user}
            return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', kwargs)
    def get(self, request):
        users =User.objects.all()
        object_list= Post.objects.filter(owner =self.request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
        args ={'object_list':object_list,'users':users}
        return render (request, self.template_name, args)
```

urls.py

```
 # profilepage
        url(r'^profile/$', views.ViewProfile.as_view(), name='view_profile'),

    # profilepage
    url(r'^profile/(?/P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ViewProfile.as_view(), name='view_profile_with_pk'),
```

profile.html

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>Friends</h1>
          {%for user in users %}
          <a href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk  %}">
            <h3>{{user.username}}</h3>
          </a>

          {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your urls.py the following:

```
url(r'^profile/(?/P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ViewProfile.as_view(), name='view_profile_with_pk'),
#                ^  this character shouldn't be here
```

should be

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ViewProfile.as_view(), name='view_profile_with_pk'),
```

Comment: Thanks that helped but now i am faced with the problem of:                     get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Comment: @Migdotcom I suspect the `get()` method that is receiving an unexpected `pk` kwarg is actually the one on your view – the one starting with `def get(self, request):`